# How do you find an expression for the sum of the first 35 terms of a logarithmic series?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$\ln(x^2/y^0) + \ln(x^2/y^1) + \ln(x^2/y^2)+ \ln(x^2/y^3)+ \ln(x^2/y^4)+ \cdots$$

Comment: By recalling that $\ln(ab) = \ln(a) + \ln(b)$

Answer (score 2):

Using the formula $\displaystyle \ln\left(\frac{m}{n}\right) = \ln(m)-\ln(n)$ and $\ln(m)^{n} = n\cdot \ln(m)$

So we can write Sum as $\displaystyle \ln\left(\frac{x^2}{y^0}\right)+ \ln\left(\frac{x^2}{y^1}\right)+.........+ \ln\left(\frac{x^2}{y^{34}}\right) $

$\displaystyle = \left[\underbrace{\ln(x^2)+\ln(x^2)+.........+\ln(x^2)}_{\bf{35-terms}}\right]-\left[\underbrace{\ln(y^0)+\ln(y^{1})+........+\ln(y^{34})}_{\bf{35-terms}}\right]$

$\displaystyle = 35\times 2\ln(x)-\ln(y)\cdot (0+1+2+3+...+34)$